# How to type the cursor caret symbol?

Tags: front-end, named-characters

I'm trying to describe in a notebook the way that the front end displays a caret where it is expecting input (e.g., in `Sin[ ]`, where it appears, by default, between the brackets).

How can one type the caret symbol?

I'm not finding it on the Special Characters palette and not finding "caret" in the documentation.

Comment: [Caret](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_(computing)): ^. If you don't want to copy it, typing it in depends on the keyboard layout you are using.

Comment: Do you mean `\[Wedge]` ?

Comment: @cvgmt: No, `\[Wedge]` puts the bottom of that symbol on the baseline, whereas the bottom of the caret is below the baseline.

Comment: Trying to copy that ephemeral (red) insertion caret just does not seem to work!

Comment: @murray, this is not a "regular" character in the cell, but some specially formatted marking in the front-end. You can play with Superscript, Font Size and Text Color, such as ``Sin[Subscript[, \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\), StyleBox["^",FontSize->14,FontWeight->"Bold", FontColor->RGBColor[1, 0, 0]]]\)  ]]`` to get something [similar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5V58.png).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest I can get is:

```
Sin[Style[Subscript["", "\[And]"], Red, FontWeight -> Bold]]
```

Which Gives:
[image]

Comment: Slightly better is `Style[Sin[Style[Subscript["", "\[And]"], Red]], FontWeight -> Bold]`.

Comment: Ahh yes, looks better with the Sin[] bold too.